# Adding data into google sheet by embedding it in my blog

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, google-docs

Is it possible to add data into google sheet from my wordpress page by embedding the google sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click File > Publish to the web > Embed, and then paste the iframe html into your wordpress post

Then back in the sheet file, click File > Share and change the permission to 'Can edit' and copy the sharing link

Then paste this sharing link over the default 'pubhtml' you previously added to you wordpress post, so that it looks something like:

isrc="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dNcQaUCaHXGt26sKwteSghwUCZPM4rTcH0oFoM/**edit?usp=sharing**?widget=true&headers=false">

An editable version of your sheet file should now appear on your wordpress post

Comment: and I have to login to gmail to see the content?

Comment: the html you generate in the first step (after clicking 'Embed') will just create a read-only copy of the file in your Wordpress post.  To make it editable, you need to replace the section between "https" and "pubhtml" with the code you get from the second step (after clicking Share).  Also, as long as you have set the permissions to 'anyone can edit' then you shouldn't need to log in to see the content